# C program using pipes gziping a file on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, pipe, fork, gzip

I'm trying to write a c program to implement the following commend on Ubuntu:

```
file | gzip newfile.gz
```

So I've read beej's guide and tried the following code:

```
int pfds[2];
char buffer[256];
pipe(pfds);
pid_t t=fork();
if (!t) {
    int bytesin;
    close(1);       /* close normal stdout */
    dup(pfds[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
    close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
    int fd = open("1",O_RDONLY);
    while (bytesin = read(fd,buffer,256) !=0){
        write(pfds[1],buffer,strlen(buffer));
    }

} else {
    waitpid(t,NULL,0);
    bzero(buffer,256);
    close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
    dup(pfds[0]);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
    close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
    execlp("gzip","myfile.gz", NULL);
}

return 0;
```

Well I read the file ok, and I get its contents via the pipe. However when I try to execute gzip, I get the following error:

```
compressed data not written to a terminal
```

help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement an incorrect command line. The filename args passed to `gzip ` are the files to be compressed not the target file. Instead, you need to implement: `cat file | gzip > newfile.gz`

Comment: `open("1",O_RDONLY)` what is this, `1` and `"1"` is completely different thinhd

Comment: what do you expect your command to do? Do you want to compress a `file` and save its gzipped version in `newfile.gz`? i.e., do you actually need to implement `gzip -c file >newfile.gz`?